# How to send the parameters to the jasper report scheduler in the url

Tags: jasperserver, job-scheduling

Is there a way to pass parameters to the scheduler of the jasper report in the url.
My requirement is that i have run a report with certain parameters and now want to send the report output as an attachment to a user with out going back and schedule it.

For this i have given an url in the report itself which opens the scheduling page of that report but the user again needs to set the parameters in the new window before sending it as the email.
Is there way that the parameters from the already run report can be passed on to the schedular so that the user just needs to enter the mail id and send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set default value to parameters while scheduling.

Instead, you can have a **java program to schedule the report with the respected parameters** and then you can allow the **user to edit the email address**.

Refer [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v55/report-scheduling-api) link for scheduling reports through java program.

Hope this should solve your problem.